# Command in Source results in prompt in Console

Tags: r

When I issue the command clustMixType::clprofiles from the RStudio Source pane and press Ctrl+Enter, it results in a prompt (Hit Return to see next plot:) in the Console. Is there a way to avoid this prompt and just show the plots?

I haven't seen this type of behavior in RStudio before (Source command issuing a prompt in the Console). Is there a way to avoid this prompt and just show the plots?

Comment: The prompt is not coming from the IDE, but from the setup of the plot function in R. I am not aware of a way around it, other than saving the output of the function into an object, and then call the object in your script file one plot at a time (i.e. `myplot[[1]]`, `myplot[[2]]`, etc).

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. The R graphics device can only show one plot at a time. How would you like to see multiple plots? So do want them to all be small squares in a larger plot or something?